# iOS Bluetooth Performing Write Long

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I'm working on a project with an iPhone connecting to an ESP32 using BLE. I'm trying to write a 528 byte long blob to a characteristic. Since the blob is longer than the max 512 allowed per write I'm trying to do a Write Long.

I'ved tried a couple things

1 - If I just try to write the blob I see the first chunk go through with Prepare Write set but there are no subsequent writes.

Why is it stopping after the first chunk?

2 - If I try to chuck it manually based on the size returned from maximumWriteValueLengthForType I see all the data is sent correctly but Prepare Write is not set so they aren't handled correctly.

How do I specify Prepare Write / Execute Write requests?

Here's a code snippet covering the implementation #2

```
      NSData *blob = [request value];
      NSUInteger localLength = 0;
      NSUInteger totalLength = [blob length];
      NSUInteger chunkSize = [peripheral maximumWriteValueLengthForType:type];
      uint8_t localBytes[chunkSize];
      NSData *localData;

      do
      {
        if(totalLength > chunkSize) {
            NSLog(@"BIGGER THAN CHUNK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            NSLog(@"%tu", chunkSize);
            for ( int i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++) {
                localBytes[i] = ((uint8_t *)blob.bytes)[localLength + i];
            }
            localData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:localBytes length:chunkSize];
            totalLength -= chunkSize;
            localLength += chunkSize;
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Smaller than chunk");
            uint8_t lastBytes[totalLength];
            for (int i = 0 ; i < totalLength; i++) {
                lastBytes[i] = ((uint8_t *)blob.bytes)[localLength + i];
            }
            localData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:lastBytes length:totalLength];
            totalLength = 0;
        }
        // Write to characteristic
        [peripheral writeValue: localData forCharacteristic:characteristic type:type];
      } while( totalLength > 0);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your code. Your second approach is correct, but we need to see how you have implemented it

Comment: The general approach is write data until your write fails. Wait for the delegate method  [`peripheralIsReady`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/2874034-peripheralisready). Start writing again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long writes are affected by the same limit of 512 bytes maximum for the characteristic value. Long writes are only useful when MTU is too short to write the full value in one packet. Maybe you're trying to write out of this allowed range or something.

Newer iOS versions communicating with BLE 5 devices use a large enough MTU to fit a characteristic value of 512 in one packet (if the remote device also supports such a big MTU).

If you want to write bigger values than 512 bytes, you will need to split it up into multiple writes, so that the second write "overwrites" the first value sent, rather than appending to it. You can also use L2CAP CoC instead which eliminates this arbitrary 512 byte limit.

Comment: How do I specify the multiple writes are Prepare Writes and then send the follow-up Execute Write?

Comment: The Bluetooth stack in iOS will automatically construct all Prepare Write and Execute Write when you try to write a value too large to fit in one Write Request according to the current MTU. Note that you will never be able to write more than 512 bytes this way in one api call.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right general approach but you can't just send the chunks sequentially.  There is a limited buffer for sending Bluetooth data and your loop will write data into that buffer more quickly than the Bluetooth hardware can send it.

The exact approach you need to take depends on whether your characteristic supports write with response or write without response.

If your characteristic uses write with response, you should send a chunk and then wait until you get a call to the [`didWriteValueFor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518823-peripheral) delegate method. You can then write the next chunk. The advantage of this approach is essentially guaranteed delivery of the data. The disadvantage is it is relatively slow.

If your characteristic uses write without response then you call `write` repeatedly until you get a call to `didWriteValueFor` with an error. At this point you have to wait until you get a call to [`peripheralIsReady`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/2874034-peripheralisready). At this point you can start writing again, beginning with the last failed write.

With this approach there is the potential for lost data, but it is faster.

If you have to move large amounts of data, an L2Cap stream might be better, but you need to handle data framing.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem so I tried just adding a quick and dirty sleep. With or without the pause all the data arrives just fine. The issue is that I'm unable to send the chunks as Prepare Write and then an Execute Write so they're not properly handled as one data block. This works fine using our python client, which uses pygatt. I'm just unable to get it working using an iPhone.

Comment: I don't follow,what you mean by "one data block". On your peripheral you will need to reassemble the chunks. You can't write more data than the characteristic can accept.

Comment: Ah yes, I was reading the BLE spec wrong. I thought with Prepare Write / Executes Write you could keep writing beyond the 512 bytes limit. Instead, those are for writing 512 bytes when the MTU size is less. Looks like the python library we are using isn't strictly following the spec. Thanks for your help!